# Change chart based on selectinput value in R

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server

I have split the window in two parts. On both parts I have a dropdown and a sunburst chart. Now I want to change the sunbursts with the dropdowns. I have dataframes like data_pie and data_pie2 and this should be changed from the dropdown value. I know I should use reactive functions, but I dont know how can I change the dataframes.

server.R

```
  output$sunburst <- renderSunburst({sunburst(data_pie, count =  TRUE, legend = list(w = 150,h = 50, s = 15 , t = 1 ), breadcrumb = list(w = 150,h = 75, s = 15 , t = 10))})

  output$sunburst2 <- renderSunburst({sunburst(data_pie2, count =  TRUE, legend = list(w = 150,h = 50, s = 15 , t = 1 ), breadcrumb = list(w = 150,h = 75, s = 15 , t = 10))})
```

ui.R

```
tabItem(tabName = "sunbrust",
        h2("Sunbrust Visualization"),
        fluidRow(

          box(
            selectInput("input_pie_links", choices = c("Model 1", "Model 2", "Model 3"), label = "Model Auswahl"),
            sunburstOutput("sunburst", width = "1200", height = "1200")),

          box(
            selectInput("input_pie_rechts", choices = c("Model 1", "Model 2", "Model 3"), label = "Model Auswahl"),
            sunburstOutput("sunburst2", width = "1200", height = "1200"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have create the following solution:

ui.R

```
tabItem(tabName = "sunbrust",
        h2("Sunbrust Visualization"),
        fluidRow(
          #column(10, align="center",
          #       sunburstOutput("sunburst", width = "1200", height = "1200")

      box(
        uiOutput("sunburst_auswahl_links"),
        sunburstOutput("sunburst", width = "1200", height = "1200")),

      box(
        uiOutput("sunburst_auswahl_rechts"),
        sunburstOutput("sunburst2", width = "1200", height = "1200"))

    )
```

server.R

```
  output$sunburst_auswahl_links <- renderUI({
    selectInput("auswahl_sunburst_links", "Model Auswahl:", c(1,2,3)) 
  })

  sunbrylinks <- reactive({sunburst(datapielist[as.integer(input$auswahl_sunburst_links)][[1]], count =  TRUE, legend = list(w = 150,h = 50, s = 15 , t = 1 ), breadcrumb = list(w = 150,h = 75, s = 15 , t = 10))})

  output$sunburst <- renderSunburst({sunbrylinks()})


  output$sunburst_auswahl_rechts <- renderUI({
    selectInput("auswahl_sunburst_rechts", "Model Auswahl:", c(1,2,3)) 
  })

  sunbryrechts <- reactive({sunburst(datapielist[as.integer(input$auswahl_sunburst_rechts)][[1]], count =  TRUE, legend = list(w = 150,h = 50, s = 15 , t = 1 ), breadcrumb = list(w = 150,h = 75, s = 15 , t = 10))})

  output$sunburst2 <- renderSunburst({sunbryrechts()})
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do. Show only one chart instead of two by using slideInput to choose the data set? Maybe the code below helps. If not please specify what you are trying to do, and also provide more code so that you dashboard can be reproduced.

ui.R

```
  tabItem(tabName = "sunbrust",
               h2("Sunbrust Visualization"),
               fluidRow(

                 box(
                   selectInput("input_pie", choices = c("Model 1" = 1, "Model 2" = 2),
                               label = "Model Auswahl"),
                   sunburstOutput("sunburst", width = "1200", height = "1200"))
               )
```

server.R

```
    data = reactive({

    if (input$input_pie == 1) {
      data <- data_pie
    } else {
        data <- data_pie2
      } 

    })

    output$sunburst <- renderSunburst({sunburst(data(), count =  TRUE, legend = list(w = 150,h = 50, s = 15 , t = 1 ), breadcrumb = list(w = 150,h = 75, s = 15 , t = 10))})
```